# selecting subset of pandas dataframe based on specified list of values

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to know if there is a way to select rows based on a list of values. That is, create a subset from a dataframe based on the values from a list.

To explain further, I take an example of a dataframe from [Chris Albon](http://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_join_merge_dataframe.html). Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
raw_data = {
        'subject_id': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
        'first_name': ['Alex', 'Amy', 'Allen', 'Alice', 'Ayoung'], 
        'last_name': ['Anderson', 'Ackerman', 'Ali', 'Aoni', 'Atiches']}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['subject_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'])
df_a
```

I only wish to choose rows based on the 'first_name' from the list below:

```
fnames = ['Alex', 'Alice', 'Ayoung']
```

What I have always done is to a run loop over the fnames with the condition:

```
for fn in fnames:
    df_name = df_a[(df_a['first_name'] == fn
```

and then append/concat each row to a new data frame to create what I desire. Is there a better way to subset a dataframe based on values from a list?

Comment: This question should be closed, see the above dupe basically you want to do `df_a[df_a['first_name'].isin(fnames)]`

Comment: Ok, thanks. Please close the question. I do not know how to?

Comment: Thanks Ed. Sorry for the dupe. Didn't know exactly what to search for.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `isin` method:

```
 df_name = df_a[(df_a['first_name'].isin(fn)
```

Comment: So, you are saying, I still need to loop over?

Comment: I tried your solution but I get an error: KeyError: "['Alex' 'Amy' 'Allen' 'Alice' 'Ayoung'] not in index"